# ui.bootstrap.accordion not working with Bootstrap v4

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui

I tried using the accordion from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion and after hours of trying and not getting the desired results, I changed the bootstrap version from 4.0.0 to 3.0.0 and everything showed up perfectly. With v4, I get this:

[image]

Only some clickable text, like a href tag. By clicking on it, sometimes it shows the content, sometimes not. I used this:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
<div uib-accordion-group class="mt-1" heading="Online friends" is-open="true">
</div>
<div uib-accordion-group class="mt-1" heading="Offline friends" is-open="false">
</div>
</uib-accordion>
```

Additional info:

- angular version: 1.6.4
- ui-bootstrap-tpls 2.5.0
- jquery 3.2.1
- bootstrap 4.0.0

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be the problem?

Bootstrap 4 is almost a complete rewrite of Bootstrap 3.

So, the two versions are **completely incompatible with each other**.

You cannot use Bootstrap 3 code with Bootstrap 4 css and vice versa.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Bootstrap 4 accordion docs:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: I know they are not backwards compatible, but the question remains: if I use v4 and want the accordion, what do I do?

Comment: I knew about collapse, but I thought there might be something from another library, as uib-accordion is. Thanks!